# Get the first sorted element with LINQ? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary, sorting

First, have a look at this code:

```
Dictionary<int,int> dict = Dictionary<int,int>();
dict[3] = 1;
dict[2] = 2;
dict[1] = 3;

foreach(KeyValuePair<int,int> item in dict.OrderByDescending(p => p.Value))
{
    print(item.Value);
    break;
}
```

This code, basically prints the value of the entry in the dictionary with the highest value. I'd like to accomplish this without using a "broken" `foreach` loop. How might I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you could do:

```
if(dict.Any())
   print(dict.Values.Max());
```

This is not only more concise, but also doesn't require sorting the dictionary out-of-place first (which is what starting an enumeration on`OrderByDescending` does), so is more efficient in both time and space.

If you need the key as well, you can use a `MaxBy` operator (such as from [moreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)) as follows:

```
if(dict.Any())
{
    var bestKvp = dict.MaxBy(kvp => kvp.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", bestKvp.Key, bestKvp.Value);
}
```

It is possible to accomplish this with standard LINQ to Objects in `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space with the `Aggregate` operator, but it's quite ugly:

```
if(dict.Any())
{
    var bestKvp = dict.Aggregate((bestSoFar, next) => bestSoFar.Value > next.Value ? bestSoFar : next );
    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", bestKvp.Key, bestKvp.Value);
}
```

Comment: Well! That seems alot simpler than using LINQ, thankyou! The one thing is, though, I need to get the key as well. Is that possible?

Comment: Actually, much of what you are looking at *is* linq. Or, to be more precise, extension methods of the IEnumerable<T> interface

Answer (score 1):

I am, for the most part, content with Ani's answer. However, I want to point out the `First<T>()` and `Last<T>()` LINQ functions.

```
var value = dict.OrderByAscending(pair => pair.Value).First();
```

Sorry I couldn't just comment, I'm a new member. You should use Ani's answer instead, however, because he is correct that his goes faster.